# Volley Library Cant Post Data To Server

Tags: java, php, android, api, android-volley

I am developing an android application for a wordpress site that have login and 
registration.

i am using volley library , it is very well connect to server ,

**BUT MY PROBLEM is that when i post parameters to api it cant create any user .**

my api works very well in POSTMAN , and had no problem .

**my api code is this :**

This is DbOperations.php

```
public function registerUser($email, $username, $password)
{

    if (username_exists($username) && email_exists($email)) {
        $error = array();
        $error['message'] = "username or email exists";
        return $error;
    }
    else {
        $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);
        if (!is_wp_error($user_id))
        {
            wp_set_password($password,$user_id);
        }
        else
        {
            $error = array();
            $error['message'] = "can not create user";
            return $error;
        }


    }
}
```

This is my register_user.php Code :

```
include ('DbOperations.php');
$dbOperate = new DbOperations();
$username = @($_POST['username']);
$password = @($_POST['password']);
$email=@($_POST['email']);
$regArray = array();
$regArray = $dbOperate->registerUser($email,$username,$password);
print_r(json_encode($regArray));
```

after this codes , here is my android studio codes : 
this is a method that i wrote inside registerActivity That when user click sign up button this method execute .
all inputs are set .

```
 private void DoSignUp()
    {

        String url = "http://192.168.43.241/wp-includes/rest-api/register_user.php";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Succeed" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username",RegUser);
                params.put("password", RegPass);
                params.put("email", RegEmail);
                return params;
            }

        };

// Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    }
```

i searched alot but not found anything , 
**i say again that my api works very well inside postman .**
i use a real device to test my app .

**finally this is what i get when click signup button on android :**

```
succeed{"message","can not crate user"}
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , Since Nobody Help Me , I tried myself and found the answer ,
The Problem was because of using JsonObjectRequest , When i use JSONObjectRequest the volley send data as a json object and my api is designd to work and receive  strings because i used these lines of codes :

```
$username = @($_POST['username']);
$email=@($_POST['email']);
$password = @($_POST['password']);
```

so i use this code instead :

```
    private void DoSignUp()
    {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, ""+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, ""+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    params.put("username", edtUserR.getText().toString().trim());
                    params.put("email", edtEmailR.getText().toString().trim());
                    params.put("password", edtPassR.getText().toString().trim());
                    return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }

}
```

and it is worked for me very well .
thanks to myself .

Answer (score 1):

Check [JsonObjectRequest](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java) Source code from github. This constructor

```
    public JsonObjectRequest(
        int method,
        String url,
        @Nullable JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONObject> listener,
        @Nullable ErrorListener errorListener)
```

accept a `JSONObject`. `jsonRequest` is used as a post data. The data you want to post. From method documentation:

> @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null indicates no
>        *     parameters will be posted along with request.

So don't pass `null` if you want to post some data. Create a `JsonObject` with your data like :

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
params.put("param1", 1);
params.put("param2", 2);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {...}
```

`getParams` method will not work for `JsonObjectRequest` because it is not called.

Comment: i tried this , but not worked , already i found my answer , thanks .